# What are the application scenarios of the Aware interface in Spring?

Tags: spring

For example, I can implements BeanNameAware and rewrite its set method to change some properties of bean objects.
But when do I need to do this? I want to know the application scenario of this approach or the benefits of this approach.

Comment: https://dzone.com/articles/spring-bean-lifecycle-using-spring-aware-interface

Answer (score 0):

After a few days of study, I have a new understanding, these Aware are similar to the functions in the bean's life cycle, such as init-method or destroy-method, I can use these hook functions to execute different tasks when the bean is initialized or destroyed. For example, adding a connection to the database in the initialization method or adding an operation to close the connection in the destroy method

Comment: It can be said that using Aware allows beans to obtain some services of Spring, but Aware is mainly used internally by Spring, and developers generally do not use Aware-related interfaces